# Extract file name from a url - jmeter regular expression extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am trying to extract the file name with jmeter regular expression extractor. my parsed url will be /xxxx/systems/fileName.ext , the file name and the extension will be dynamic. so I can't use any static name in the parser. All I know is the third / . I tried with multiple combinations . but no luck. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you've already tried something, could you edit into your question so we can help you pin down where exactly you went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you everything at the end of the string that isn't a forward slash:

```
[^/]+$
```

Broken down:

`[^/]` - Match a character that isn't a forward slash

`+` - Match one or more (as many as possible)

`$` - Match at the end of the string

Comment: Thanks, it works, I tried with \z for matching at the end of target string, that is wrong.